# Externally declared (global) variable in Fortran

Tags: variables, fortran, global, subroutine

I want to know if it's possible to declare a variable and have declaration carry over to another subroutine or program (hence become global)

For example

```
program main
    implicit none
    call mysub
    print *, x
end program main

subroutine mysub
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: x = 1
end subroutine mysub
```

Would print "1"

Is this possible? I want to do this because a program I'm working on has large sets of variables that I would rather avoid copying unless necessary.

Comment: It is possible to have "global" variables - but not like this.  If you explain what it is you want to do, with a short example, we can give you a more helpful answer, perhaps.

Comment: The best way to do this is typically with modules; there are many helpful guides on how to use modules in fortran.

Answer (score 7):

The most straightforward way to do this in modern Fortran is with modules.

Consider

```
module globals
  implicit none
  integer :: x
end module globals

program main
  use globals
  implicit none
  call mysub
  print *,x
end program main

subroutine mysub
  use globals
  implicit none
  x = 1
end subroutine mysub
```

In this paradigm you specify your "global" variables within the module and `use` that module everywhere you want access to them.

If you are just using this to declare contants (parameters) you can simplify this to:

```
module globals
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: x=1
end module globals

program main
  use globals
  implicit none
  print *,x
end program main
```

---

The older method to accomplish this involved `common` blocks and `include`ing files that declared them every procedure that accessed them. If you find a tutorial dealing with the `common` block method I advise you to ignore them and avoid their use in new code.